# Is there a way to group a dynamic string one basis of fixed conditions

Tags: regex

Example strings:

```
sjdjd|shjdjd,A|shdahdajh,E|hsdhsdj,C|asnma,A
shabnmun|sjddamd,E|wqhsbn,E,teyiuiw,S|ssbxnsmcn,A|vscnbdcmdn,E
sanbsnk|scbdcbd,A
```

I want to create 5 groups:

1. Includes the 1st string which comes before the first `|` - "sjdjd" in the first example
2. All the strings having `,A` in the delimited section
3. All the strings having `,E` in the delimited section
4. All the strings having `,C` in the delimited section
5. All the strings having `,S` in the delimited section

The pattern I tried:

```
^(?:.+)\|(.+)\|(?:.+)\|(?:.+)\|(?:.+)+$
```

Expected groups

> (Group 1 - sjdjd, shabnmun, sanbsnk), (Group 2 - shjdjd, asnma,
>   ssbxnsmcn, scbdcbd), (Group 3 - shdahdajh, sjddamd, wqhsbn,
>   vscnbdcmdn), (Group 4 - hsdhsdj), (Group 5 - teyiuiw)

Comment: Please show us the result which you want, based on the example string.

Comment: (Group 1 - sjdjd, shabnmun, sanbsnk), (Group 2 - shjdjd, asnma, ssbxnsmcn, scbdcbd), (Group 3 - shdahdajh, sjddamd, wqhsbn, vscnbdcmdn), (Group 4 - hsdhsdj), (Group 5 - teyiuiw)

Comment: Please edit the question and show us all the groups that you want, and in which for you want.

Comment: Added the expected groups in comment

Comment: What Language/Tool are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to just do multiple searches and assemble:

```
import re

s = """sjdjd|shjdjd,A|shdahdajh,E|hsdhsdj,C|asnma,A
shabnmun|sjddamd,E|wqhsbn,E,teyiuiw,S|ssbxnsmcn,A|vscnbdcmdn,E
sanbsnk|scbdcbd,A"""

l1 = re.findall(r'^[^|]+', s, flags=re.MULTILINE)
lA = re.findall(r'(?<=[|,])[^|,]+(?=,A)', s)
lE = re.findall(r'(?<=[|,])[^|,]+(?=,E)', s)
lC = re.findall(r'(?<=[|,])[^|,]+(?=,C)', s)
lS = re.findall(r'(?<=[|,])[^|,]+(?=,S)', s)

groups = [l1, lA, lE, lC, lS]
for group in groups:
    print(group)
```

Prints:

```
['sjdjd', 'shabnmun', 'sanbsnk']
['shjdjd', 'asnma', 'ssbxnsmcn', 'scbdcbd']
['shdahdajh', 'sjddamd', 'wqhsbn', 'vscnbdcmdn']
['hsdhsdj']
['teyiuiw']
```

[See Demo](http://ideone.com/fMQfee)